# How do I enable a configuration in a Kernel?

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, configuration, manjaro, kernel-parameters

As the title says, I am trying to enable KASAN in my Manjaro distribution for a project, but I have no idea how to.

The documentation here (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/dev-tools/kasan.html) says just to

```
CONFIG_KASAN = y
```

but I have no idea where to do and what steps should I take before that, I haven't configured the kernel before, I am a beginner.

So far I have found out that I can see what configurations are done by looking at

```
/proc/config.gz
```

Here it says that KASAN is not enabled, but I don't know where to go from here. Should I just do an echo `CONFIG_KASAN= y`, or do I have to rebuild the Kernel and such?

Please help me.

Comment: I want to add that I have tried doing echo to the /proc/config.gz file, but it gets denied even when I use sudo.

Comment: Yes, you have to rebuild the kernel. Google "how to build a Linux kernel" or similar. Basically, do `make menuconfig` in the kernel directory, find the Kasan entry, and enable it, and enable other configurations you might need for that. Then build the kernel, different distros have potentially helpers for that (Debian does), I don't know what Arch uses.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the build tools installed:

`pacman -S base-devel` (hit enter to install all)

1. Download the kernel source from https://www.kernel.org/
2. Extract the tar to `/usr/src/` or `/usr/local/src` (ie. `tar xvJf linux-5.6.5.tar.xz`)
3. cd into the new directory `/usr/src/linux-5.6.5`
4. type `make menuconfig` (find your KASAN setting here and change it) save `.config` file and exit (or if you didn't find it: edit `.config` file with your favorite editor and set KASAN setting there by searching for keyword and changing the value).

Here is a guide how to build the kernel the manjaro way.
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-compile-the-mainline-kernel-the-manjaro-way/51700

Make backups!
Good luck.

Comment: I strongly recommend using the existing kernel configuration as a starting point, not the default that comes with the kernel source archive. Otherwise you will get a very different set of config settings. After step 3 above, run `zcat /proc/config.gz > .config` to copy the running kernel's configuration into .config, then run `make menuconfig` and change the settings you want.

Comment: @JohanMyréen and Michael D thank you! Is there anyway that I could work on the kernel that's running on my machine now, or does it have to be a newly downloaded one?

Comment: After reconfiguration, you will have to compile, install, and reboot into the new kernel. This is because you have made a change to the kernel program, and for the change to have an effect, you will have to restart the kernel using the new image.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure the kernel from source with `make menuconfig`, to go "Kernel Hacking" ---> "Memory debugging" ---> Enable "KASAN:: runtime memory debugger"